# How to get full text from the editText by using addTextChangedListener in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to add full text from the editText into an array. But while running this code the array 
    values will be like first word , second word etc. How to get the full sentence and i want to add it 
    into an array(Already did it using interface)

Note : The code is placed on the recyclerview adapter , 
Where texBox is the EditText and examinationListener is the interface used

Here i shared the code. Please check it.

```
 textBox.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                    textFromBox = s.toString()
                    examinationListener.addAnswer(textFromBox)
                }

                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                                               count: Int, after: Int) {

                }

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int,
                                           before: Int, count: Int) {

                }

            })
```

Comment: Do you have many editTexts?

Comment: yes it's a recyclerview

Comment: Let me get it. You want to add text of editeText to array. Right?

Comment: yes. when i tried the above mentioned code. I got array like [g, gs, gsg, gsgf, gsgfu, gsgfut, gsgfuty, gsgfutyy]

Comment: I added an answer. If I understood correct , it will be as like the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
    textFromBox = textBox.text.toString()
    examinationListener.addAnswer(textFromBox)
}
```

Comment: when i tried the above mentioned code. I got array like [g, gs, gsg, gsgf, gsgfu, gsgfut, gsgfuty, gsgfutyy]

Comment: OK，I misunderstood that you want an array. Are you actually want a sentence without `,` and `[] `?

Answer (score 0):

I created an array up to the list size. Each items of RecyclerView have an EditText.

```
val array = arrayOfNulls<String>(listSize)
```

We need to know the position of EditText to add to the array. Change interface like this:

```
interface ExaminationListener {
   fun addAnswer(text: String, position: Int)
}
```

function addAnswer:

```
override fun addAnswer(text: String, position: Int) {
   array[position] = text // we add every changes to the array. 
}
```

This use is more useful. We don't need other methods:

```
textBox.doAfterTextChanged { 
   examinationListener.addAnswer(it.toString(), position) // you can use adapterPosition if that is in Viewholder
}
```

We create a sentence from array elements. You can see your full sentence:

```
val sentence = array.filterNotNull().joinToString (separator = " ") { it -> it }

Log.d("Sentence" , sentence)
```

Comment: could you please mention the steps

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple just add a `TextWatcher` to your `EditText` like:

```
    val answerWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(value: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(value: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            when {
                // Here value is your full text from your EditText
                value.toString().equals("I am a sentence", ignoreCase = true) -> {

                }

                else -> {
                    // Just a test condition
                }

            }
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {

        }
    }

    // Add this TextWatcher to your EditText
    edittext.addTextChangedListener(answerWatcher)
```